# difference between nested structure / classes and declaring class instances within a class

Tags: c++

Suppose we have two structures, bigguy and foryou.

We could declare them like this:

```
struct bigguy
{
    struct foryou
    {
        int survivors;
    }cia, pavel;
};
```

or we could declare them like this:

```
struct foryou
{
    int survivors;
};

struct bigguy
{
    foryou cia;
    foryou pavel;
};
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each type of declaration? Does it depend on the program's purpose? Is one method considered better practice than the other? (Assume that in the hypothetical program there is an actual reason to not just declare everything as a single structure.)

Comment: _"Does it depend on the program's purpose?"_ Of course. Its just a way to organize scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some advantages of nested struct over several structs:

- You have the ability to hide the nested struct in the `private` section. Hence the rest of your code does not need to take care of it.
- Refactoring could be easier.
- Every derived class of `bigguy` will naturally see `foryou` even if they are in different namespaces or scopes. It is also interesting for nested `enum` since you can refer to the enumerated constants without prefixing them by a namespace context.

Here are some advantages of several structs over nested structs.

- If you want to use the `foryou` struct outside the `bigguy` class, you need to prefix it with `bigguy::` which is sometimes an heavy syntax. Note that `auto` is interesting to avoid such declarations.
- you will have more understandable compiler messages if `bigguy` is a template class and you will avoid some uses of `typename`. In fact if `bigguy` is a template class and if `foryou` does not need the template parameters, several structs is preferred. Better you can derive your `bigguy` templated class from a non-template class that has `foryou` inside.